# Construct an isosceles based tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

I've searched the forum and didn't find any answer to my question, I need to construct a Tetrahedron with an isosceles triangle for the base.

$AB = AC = 10.5$ cm

$BC = 17.5$ cm

and I need the height of the tetrahedron from its gravity point to be $4.5$ cm.

Doing some basic Pythagore from the BC segment I found the length of the two projected segments to be $10.26$ cm but I'm not even sure that's right.

Since I can't find a rectangular triangle with two known lengths from $AB $ or $AC$ I don't know how to get the other length.

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the height of the tetrahedron from it's gravity point"? Do you mean that the the projection of the forth vertex onto the base plane is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of $\triangle ABC$? What values do you need for the construction of the tetrahedron?

Comment: Oh yes sorry used the wrong word, I meant the centroid. What do you mean by what values do I need ? The one I gave are insufficient ?

Comment: Quite opposite. I think that the given values are completely sufficient for constructing the tetrahedron. But you apparently have a different opinion. The question is: what additional parameters do *you* need for construction of the tetrahedron? Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

The centroid $C$ always lies on $1/3$ of the medians, you can read about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle). Since your triangle is isosceles, the median that connects $A$ to $BC$ intersects $BC$ exactly in the middle $M$, which results in right-angled triangles $AMB$, $AMC$. I am not sure what measurements you are searching for, but here are some formulas. Let's call the top point $H$.

\begin{align}
\overline{BM} &= \frac{1}{2}\overline{BC} \\
\overline{AM} ^2 &= \overline{AB}^2+\overline{BM}^2 \\
\overline{AC} &= \frac{2}{3} \overline{AM} \\
\overline{CM} &= \frac{1}{3} \overline{AM} \\
\overline{BC}^2 &= \overline{BM}^2 + \overline{CM}^2 \\
\overline{AH}^2 &= \overline{AC}^2 + \overline{CH}^2 \\
\overline{BH}^2 &= \overline{BC}^2 + \overline{CH}^2 
\end{align}
[image]